# how do we know that the rank of AB will be less than a number?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is 3 by 2 and B is 2 by 3 matrix, why is the rank of AB at most 2? 
Wouldn't AB be a matrix of 3 by 3 dimensions,  so max rank of AB would be 3?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The key is to think through how matrix multiplication works.  Each column of $AB$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.  (In general, the $j$-th column of $AB$ is the linear combination of the two columns of $A$ using the two entries in the $j$-th column of $B$ as the coefficients.)

Thus every column of $AB$ will belong to the column space of $A$.  Using the definition / properties of rank allows you to draw your conclusion.

The end result is the maximum rank of a $3 \times 3$ matrix is $3$, but the maximum rank of a $3 \times 3$ matrix that can be written as a $3 \times 2$ matrix times a $2 \times 3$ matrix is $2$.  Evidently, not every $3 \times 3$ matrix can be factored as a $3 \times 2$ matrix times a $2 \times 3$ matrix, a fact which is not obvious without thinking about ranks!